# Error prompt in comparison between a value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi i have some error regarding this code..

the error prompt : Scene 1, Layer 'qn1actionscript', Frame 71, Line 3   1176: Comparison between a value with static type flash.utils:Timer and a possibly unrelated type int.

```
if((myscore==60)&&(myTimer<=300 )){smiley.visible=true}
else
{smiley.visible=false}
```

Comment: it seems _myTimer_ is a type of _flash.utils:Timer_, so you can't compare it with integer. May be you have local variable that overrides global with the same names?

Comment: Check `currentCount` of your `myTimer` , like `myTimer.currentCount<=300` . Docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#currentCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myTimer.currentCount will count each tick...so if your timer has been called something like

```
myTimer=new Timer(300,1),  
then your condition should be 
if((myscore==60)&&(myTimer.currentCount<=1))
```